# How to replace the pressing Button by the entered value button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm a new programmer in flutter and i have a question about the flutter hello world project How can I enter the desired value directly without pressing the button every time to access it For example, enter the number 40 without pressing 40 times on the button?

```
......

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use TextFormFiled Widget to change value

```
 final TextEditingController mycontroller;


  TextFormField(
 onChanged: () {
        setState() {
             _counter = mycontroller.text;
        }
        ;
     
      },
      validator: validator,
      controller: mycontroller,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: hinttext.tr,
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        label: Text(labeltext.tr),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
      
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: error :The argument type 'Null Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)'.

Answer (score 0):

```
 void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter += 40;
    });
  }
```

Comment: but like this the value don't change dynamically when i want to change it in the textformfield

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String _counter = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 28.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _counter = value;
                  });
                },

                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter Number',
                  floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                  label: Text('Enter Number'),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),

                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
             SizedBox(height: 40,),
             Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```